# Is there any way to know if picked video is bigger than the max duration set, on edit screen

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4

I want to give a message about max duration of the video when the user is on video edit screen and has picked bigger video than the max limit. Although ImagePicker gives a message that "Video too long to send" but doesn't tell that exact limit and I want to tell that. And as this message is not customizable, I want to give a custom toast message but need that event/delegate to show. [image].

Comment: Make an `AVAsset` and there is property `asset.duration` it will be  `CMTime` you can convert it into seconds as well `CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)`. And what about Edit screen are you talking about apple's one? Then its not possible.

Comment: This I can do in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delgate.. Right? but i want to tell this to user when he is on edit screen. n yes, I m talking about apple's video edit screen.

Comment: I guess Its not possible to change the alert. You can only set the `maxDuration` like `imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 15.0f`.

Comment: Okay... n thxs @TheTiger